# Complexity of Set operations

Tags: java, set, complexity-theory

This is what I am doing:
String one = "some string"
String two = "some string"

I want to know all the characters that are in string **one** and **two** and they should come in order as they are in string one

I wrote a Java program which by using Collections performs set operations on both the collection.
What I would like to know that what is the complexity of performing set operations, is it polynomial time or linear time

My program is here

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package careercup.google;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author learner
 */
public class CharaterStringsIntersection {
    private static final String one = "abcdefgabcfmnx";
    private static final String two = "xbcg";

    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<Character> l_one = new ArrayList<Character>();
        List<Character> l_two = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for(int i=0; i<one.length(); i++){
           l_one.add(one.charAt(i));
        }
        for(int j=0; j<two.length(); j++){
            l_two.add(two.charAt(j));
        }

        l_one.retainAll(l_two);

        Iterator iter = l_one.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(" > " + iter.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
run:
 > b
 > c
 > g
 > b
 > c
 > x
```

Comment: You can use LinkedHashSet to get the performance of a Set while retaining order.  Note: you only need to retain order in the first collection, the order of the second is not important??  Do you need to keep duplicates? if so, the first collection must be a list, but the second collection can still be a set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its complexity is O(N * (N + M)), where N = `one.length()`, M = `two.length()`.

It works in the following way: for each character of `l_one` (there are N of them) it scans `l_two` (since `l_two` is an `ArrayList`, scan is linear, so it takes O(M) steps, see [1]) and removes item from `l_one` if necessary (removing from `ArrayList` takes O(N), see [1]), so you get O(N * (N + M)).

You can lower the complexity to O(N * M) by using `LinkedList` for `l_one` (since removing from `LinkedList` is O(1), see [2]), and further
lower it to O(N * log(M)) by using `TreeSet` for `l_two` (since searching in `TreeSet` takes O(log(M)), see [3]).

**References:**

1. *All of the other operations run in linear time* ([`ArrayList` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html))
2. *All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked list*, ([`LinkedList` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html))
3. *This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (`add`, `remove` and `contains`)* ([`TreeSet` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html))

Comment: Are the complexity of Java collection methods guaranteed/specified (in the way that the STL gives guarantees)?  I couldn't find anything in the Javadocs...

Comment: @Oli: I added the references.

Comment: you have a typo in TreeSet takes O(M) - it should be O(log(M)), as you correctly use that in the total complexity

Answer (score 4):

I think the more important question you are trying to ask is what is the complexity of retainAll() function. Assuming there are no hashes or quick look up, I would assume the time complexity is O(n^2). One loop to iterate the list and one loop to compare each item.

Comment: Something tells me this is an interview question ;) I think you should start thinking of other data structures. If you use a hash, this problem could be O(n)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong collection for your purposes..

Since you are doing it with plain `ArrayList` the complexity wouldn't be good, I don't know the inner implementation but I would guess it's quadratic (since it has to scroll both lists), this unless Java internally converts two lists to sets before doing the intersection.

You should start from `Set` interface ([here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)) and choose which collection is more suitable for your needs, I think that a `HashSet` (constant time) or a `TreeSet` (logarithmic but able to keep natural ordering) would be best solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly:

- `ArrayList.add()` is `O(1)`.
- `ArrayList.retainAll(other)` is `O(N1 * N2)` where `N1` is the size of `this` and `N2` is the size of `other`.  (The actual cost depends on the ratio of elements retained to elements removed.)
- `iter.hasNext()` and `iter.next()` are `O(1)` for an `ArrayList` iterator.

This is all as you would expect, based on mentally modelling an ArrayList as a Java array.