# Efficient search in datastructure ArrayList

Tags: java, android, search, data-structures, quadtree

I've an ArrayList which contains my nodes. A node has a source, target and costs. Now I have to iterate over the whole ArrayList. That lasts for for over 1000 nodes a while. Therefore I tried to sort my List by source. But to find the corresponding pair in the List I tried the binary search. Unfortunately that works only if I want to compare either source or target. But I have to compare both to get the right pair. Is there another possibility to search an ArrayList efficient?

Comment: How do you do the search? You have to match both of the items of the pair? or you need to be able to search for records matching only one of the items of each pair?

Comment: I added a bit of code to the answer I provided. I hope it will prove useful!

Comment: Where is the data coming from? The data you are using in the 1000 nodes, where are you getting it from?

Comment: Could you please review the answers and accept one if you think it served you well? If not, please leave further comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. `ArrayList`s are not made to be efficiently searched. They are used to store data and not search it. If you want to merely know if an item is contained, I would suggest you use `HashSet` as the lookup will have a time complexitiy of O(1) instead of O(n) for the ArrayList (assuming that you have implemented a functioning `equals` method for your objects).

If you want to do fast searches for objects, I recommend using an implementation of `Dictionnary` like `HashMap`. If you can afford the space requirement, you can have multiple maps, each with different keys to have a fast lookup of your object no matter what key you have to search for. Keep in mind that the lookup also requires implementing a correct `equals` method. Unfortunately, this requires that each key be unique which may not be a brilliant idea in your case.

However, you can use a `HashMap`to store, for each source, a List of nodes that have the keyed source as a source. You can do the same for cost and target. That way you can reduce the number of nodes you need to iterate over substantially. This should prove to be a good solution with a scarcely connected network.

```
private HashMap<Source, ArrayList<Node>> sourceMap = new HashMap<Source, ArrayList<Node>>();
private HashMap<Target, ArrayList<Node>> targetMap = new HashMap<Target, ArrayList<Node>>();
private HashMap<Cost, ArrayList<Node>> costMap = new HashMap<Cost, ArrayList<Node>>();

/** Look for a node with a given source */
for( Node node : sourceMap.get(keySource) )
{
    /** Test the node for equality with a given node. Equals method below */
    if(node.equals(nodeYouAreLookingFor) { return node; }
}
```

In order to be sure that your code will work, be sure to overwrite the `equals` method. I know I have said so already but this is a very common mistake.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object)
{ 
    if(object instanceof Node)
    {
        Node node = (Node) object;
        if(source.equals(node.getSource() && target.equals(node.getTarget()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you don't, the test will simply compare references which may or may not be equal depending on how you handle your objects.

**Edit:** Just read what you base your equality upon. The equals method should be implemented in your node class. However, for it to work, you need to implement and override the equals method for the source and target too. That is, if they are objects. Be watchful though, if they are `Node`s too, this may result in quite some tests spanning all of the network.

**Update:** Added code to reflect the purpose of the code in the comments.

```
ArrayList<Node> matchingNodes = sourceMap.get(desiredSourde).retainAll(targetMap.get(desiredTarget));
```

Now you have a list of all nodes that match the source and target criteria. Provided that you are willing to sacrifice a bit of memory, the lookup above will have a complexity of O(|sourceMap| * (|sourceMap|+|targetMap|)) [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010697/complexity-of-set-operations). While this is superior to just a linear lookup of all nodes, O(|allNodeList|), if your network is big enough, which with 1000 nodes I think it is, you could benefit much. If your network follows a naturally occurring network, then, as Albert-László Barabási has shown, it is likely scale-free. This means that splitting your network into lists of at least source and target will likely (I have no proof for this) result in a scale-free size distribution of these lists. Therefore, I believe the complexity of looking up source and target will be substantially reduced as |sourceMap| and |targetMap| should be substantially lower than |allNodeList|.

Comment: That's actually not that what I want. I created now a Map<cost, Map<Source, Target>>. So now I have a node with source =3 and target =6 Therefore I have to search through to find the one and only element which has a source with 3 and a target with 6. Because there can be also a Node with Source is 3 and target is 8.

Comment: Reposted comment due to error! 
Yes but the set you have to search is substantially reduced. What I would propose is that you try it the way I noted and then do the following: Get the set of all nodes with a source of 3, get all nodes with a target of 8, get the intersection of both sets. You will then have a set containing all nodes with a source of three and a target of 8. For the intersection, have a look at Java's retainAll(List) method. I can provide an example if you wish!

Comment: FYI, as of Java 7, you no longer need to verbose, redundant `HashMap<Source, ArrayList<Node>> sourceMap = new HashMap<Source, ArrayList<Node>>();`.  Instead, you can write: `HashMap<Source, ArrayList<Node>> sourceMap = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to combine the source and target into a single comparator, e.g.

```
compare(T o1, T o2) {
    if(o1.source < o2.source) { return -1; }
    else if(o1.source > o2.source) { return 1; }
    // else o1.source == o2.source
    else if(o1.target < o2.target) { return -1; }
    else if(o1.target > o2.target) { return 1; }
    else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.compareTo()` method to compares your nodes.

Comment: I tried it with compareTo(), but I need to be sure that source and target are the same as in the node with which I'm comparing. Therefore it is not possible to do it with compareTo().

Answer (score 0):

You can create two ArrayLists. The first sorted by source, the second sorted by target.
Then you can search by source or target using binarySearch on the corresponding List.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a helper class to store source-target pairs:

```
class SourceTarget {

    public final Source source; // public fields are OK when they're final and immutable.
    public final Target target; // you can use getters but I'm lazy
                                // (don't give this object setters. Map keys should ideally be immutable)

    public SourceTarget( Source s, Target t ){
        source = s;
        target = t;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object other ){
        // Implement in the obvious way (only equal when both source and target are equal
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        // Implement consistently with equals
    }
}
```

Then store your things in a `HashMap<SourceTarget, List<Node>>`, with each source-target pair mapped to the list of nodes that have exactly that source-target pair.
To retrieve just use

```
List<Node> results = map.get( new SourceTarget( node.source, node.target ) );
```

---

Alternatively to making a helper class, you can use the comparator in Zim-Zam's answer and a `TreeMap<Node,List<Node>>` with a representative `Node` object acting as the `SourceTarget` pair.