# Faster way to find index of String in ArrayList

Tags: java, list, indexof

So I have something like this:

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
```

When I println it I have:

```
"[ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL]"
```

And I want to search for example index of "E". I was doing it in this way:

```
for (String a : test) {
   if(a.contains("E")) {
      System.out.println(test.indexOf(a));
   }
}
```

Is any faster way to do this? Because now I'm evrytime making "for" on all list.

Comment: Is the list ordered?

Comment: Do you want to find all items in the array list that contain "E", or just the first?

Comment: Can you change the structure holding the data - e.g. not being an array list but let's say a map with keys - the 26 letters of the English alphabet?

Comment: Yes, I want just first element which contains "E".

Comment: have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278725/efficient-search-in-datastructure-arraylist

Comment: is your intention to look for single-character strings only? if yes, then you can use hovanessyan's advise.

Answer (score 0):

Given you've said you want to find the first item in the list that contains an "E", by definition you will have to loop through every item to check them until you find a match - this might be at the end of the list, so in the worst case you still have to search the entire list.

However, one shortcut you can take is to at least exit the loop as soon as you find the one you're interested in:

```
for (String a : test) {
   if(a.contains("E")) {
      System.out.println(test.indexOf(a));
      break;
   }
}
```

If you were searching for a complete string (e.g. "ABC") you could use `indexOf`, but as you're searching for a partial match you can't do this.

Java 8 syntax, while unlikely to speed up performance or do the operation in fewer lines of code, is arguably more readable, and will allow you to chain other stream operations to do whatever you need to do to the items that match your query:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL");
Optional<String> matchingItem = list.stream()
                                    .filter(s -> s.contains("E"))
                                    .findFirst();
matchingItem.ifPresent(s -> System.out.println(list.indexOf(s)));
```

Java 8 does contain optimisations for operations like this.

Incidentally, if your list is very large, you may find a speed improvement by using `parallelStream()` instead of `stream()` - this Java 8 code probably does the same number of operations as your code, but it is parallelisable over multiple CPU cores where a traditional for-loop is not.

Alternatively, if you really do need a way of accessing the required elements immediately, and the criteria you're looking for is always the same (i.e. you're always going to want just the elements that contain an "E"), you can track the data in an additional data structure, like a map.  E.g. every time you add an item to the list that contains the criteria you want, you also add it to the map.  Something like:

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapOfValuesICareAbout = new HashMap<>();
String newValue = "GFE";
if (newValue.contains("E")) {
    mapOfValuesICareAbout.get("E").add(newValue);
}
list.add(newValue);
```

Comment: `Is any faster way to do this?` It means that he wants to get a faster way not a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Understood, but at the beginning of my answer I state that by definition there is no faster way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **permuted index**, normally used for words:

```
["he speaks well", "well done"]
```

would give a sorted list

```
     well *done*
          *he* speaks well
       he *speaks* well
he speaks *well*
          *well* done
```

where you can find "well" fast.

Such a list entry in our case would be:

```
class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {
    String right;
    String left;

    @Override
    public String toString() { return left + "^" + right; }
}
```

For every string of length N, there are `right` values of N, N-1, ..., 2, 1 characters.

```
class SearchBase {
    private List<Entry> entries; // Or immediately sorted: TreeSet

    void addAll(String... terms) {
        fill list entries, and sort them
    }

    Collection<String> termsContaining(String sought) {
        binary search on entries rigth
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the index of the first element which contains the letter 'E' you can spare one operation by only using `String#indexOf(char)`. After you've found the element you can break out of the loop.

```
List<String> test = Arrays.asList("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL");
for (String element : test) {
    int idx = element.indexOf('E');
    if (idx != -1) {
        System.out.println(element + " with 'E' at pos: " + idx);
        break;
    }
}
```